# Can we use Net​Named​Pipe​Binding in WCF without using port?

Tags: c#, wcf, netnamedpipebinding

I am trying to implement a demo to communicate between two applications on a same machine. So I choose `Net​Named​Pipe​Binding`. And the doc of it shows that we need to assign the base address like 'http://localhost:8000/uesamples/service'

in

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding?view=netframework-4.7.

But I prefer not to use the port.

So is it possible that we can define the base address in another way?

Comment: NamedPipe bindings have no port. You have copied the wrong URL from the link you've shown (that's a HTTP binding, hence the `http://` scheme). A valid URI for the named pipe binding starts with "net.pipe"; incidentally the very next line in the sample from the linked page (`string address = "net.pipe://localhost/uesamples/calc";`)..

Comment: Yes, but I'm still confused that the url of  base address is 'http://' in the sample from the linked page. If NamedPipe bindings do not need port, why do they use the base address like that?

Comment: The base address will only be applied to those (endpoint) addresses that are _relative_. Additionally, a service can have multiple end points with different protocols. Typically, you use a http base address because that makes some framework provided endpoints that usually use the http protocol (like mex) easier to configure. Other than that it is mostly a matter of choice.

Comment: Agree, if I use the http base address, I can easily generate a code file and a config file by using command 'svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs /config:app.config http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service?wsdl'. It is different from the doc because it has '?wsdl' at the end of the base address. And I have no idea what the command will be if I use base address like 'net.pipe://localhost/uesamples/calc' or actually I don't need the base address?

Comment: You should resource stackoverflow for that information, or ask a new question. The comments are no good fit anymore.